# Парсинг next_page на PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Не переходит на следующую страницу для последующего парсинга (перебрасывает на на ту же)

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

include_once('curl_query.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
set_time_limit(0);

$url = curl_get("https://rezka.ag/films/");
$dom = str_get_html($url);
$films = $dom->find('.b-content__inline_item');
// echo $films ."<br>";


// Находим ссылки пагинации
$next_page_url = $dom->find('.b-navigation a', 0)->href;
echo $next_page_url;

echo "<items>";
echo "<next_page_url>http://34.90.104.32/kinolive/hdrezka2.php?page=$next_page_url</next_page_url>";

foreach($films as $film) {
    $title = $film->find('.b-content__inline_item-link', 0)->plaintext;
    $title = trim($title);

    $odin = $film->find('a', 0)->href;
    echo $title ."<br>";

}

echo '</items>';
```

Подскажите что не так в коде?

Comment: В __каком месте__ и __что__ здесь должно перебрасывать на следующую страницу?

Comment: В <next_page_url> . $next_page_url содержит ссылку для парсинга следующей страницы

Comment: Ну допустим, а дальше что?

Comment: Далбше нужно, что бы при переходе по <next_page_url> открывалась https://rezka.ag/films/page/2/ и так далее

Comment: Но в представленном коде нет никакой функции перехода по `next_page_url`

Comment: Не поможете? Только учусь)

Comment: Вы можете пояснить __с чем помочь__? Я уже спросил вас - __что__ в представленном коде должно по вашему мнению "переходить на следующую страницу"? Вы мне ответили что?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы парсилась ссылка https://rezka.ag/films/page/2/, потом https://rezka.ag/films/page/3/ и так далее

Comment: Ну так может надо эту ссылку передать в метод `curl_get("https://rezka.ag/films/")`?

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @beats Уточните Ваш вопрос. Вы хотите сделать кнопку, а точнее несколько кнопок для парсинга страниц?

Answer (score 0):

Надо проводить вот эту операция с новым url(который получили из сайта)

```
$url = curl_get("новый url");
$dom = str_get_html($url);
$films = $dom->find('.b-content__inline_item');
```